# サイドメニューの幅を広げても、ボタンの押下範囲の幅が変化しません。

Tags: jquery-mobile

jquery mobileを用いてサイドメニューを作りました。
デフォルトのサイドメニューの幅が狭かったので".ui-panel{width:50%;}"を指定する事で、
サイドメニュー及び内部のボタンの幅を広げました。
しかし、ボタンの押下できる範囲は広がっておらず、デフォルトの幅を超えるとマウスオーバーしても反応がありません。ボタンを押してもサイドメニューの範囲外を押されたと認識されてしまったのかサイドメニューが閉じてしまいます。
どのように対応すればサイドメニュー幅と内部コンテツの同期がとれるのでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<html>
 <head> 
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>sample</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div data-role="page">
   <div data-role="header">
    <a href="#menu-left" data-role="button" data-icon="bars" >サイドメニュー</a>
   </div>                    
   
   <div data-role="panel" id="menu-left" data-display="overlay">
      <ul data-role="listview">
        <li><a href="#anchor1">anchor1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#anchor2">anchor2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#anchor3">anchor3</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <style>
   .ui-panel{width:50%;}
  </style>
  
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

メニューを開くと、右にこういった要素が生成されていますね。

```html
<div style="height: 300px;" class="ui-panel-dismiss ui-panel-dismiss-position-left ui-panel-dismiss-display-overlay ui-panel-dismiss-open"></div>
```

メニューの外をクリックした時に、そのイベントを受けてメニューを閉じるための物でしょう。
これの位置は`left`でメニューの幅をハードコーディングする事で設定してあるようです。

あちらこちらに数値がハードコーディングされていると修正はとても面倒ですが、とりあえずはこのように上書きすればよいです。

```css
.ui-panel-dismiss-open.ui-panel-dismiss-position-left {
    left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<html>
 <head> 
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>sample</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div data-role="page">
   <div data-role="header">
    <a href="#menu-left" data-role="button" data-icon="bars" >サイドメニュー</a>
   </div>                    
   
   <div data-role="panel" id="menu-left" data-display="overlay">
      <ul data-role="listview">
        <li><a href="#anchor1">anchor1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#anchor2">anchor2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#anchor3">anchor3</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <style>
.ui-panel{width:50%;}
.ui-panel-dismiss-open.ui-panel-dismiss-position-left {
    left: 50%;
}
  </style>
  
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: 早速のご回答ありがとうございます。示して頂いた内容で無事解決致しました。jQueryMobileのCSSを見てみると、ui-panel関連の所々に"17em"と指定されていました。".ui-panel{width:50%;}"だけを上書きしてもダメという事ですね。勉強になりました！